# Is there a Protocol Buffers for Python wrapper that would allow object annotation in Python code not it proto files?

Tags: python, serialization, protocol-buffers

So I have an object model in python. My application is in development stage so currently I can allow unstable serialization format. I want annotate my object hierarchy in Python code (if needed) or annotate nothing at all allowing some Protobuf wrapper to do it all dynamically.

It would be a real pain to describe each object in plain proto files and keep booth hierarchies up to date.

So I wonder if there is a way to use Protocol Buffers in python annotating\relying on reflection in python code (alike they do it in [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net#1-first-decorate-your-classes))?

Comment: I'm certain it's possible, but whether someone has done it yet is a different question :) Do you want to generate a proto file, or skip that step altogether? What do you want to happen if you don't annotate? (Maybe it's because I'm not super familiar with annotations, but a simple example would be very helpful too.)

Comment: Abilety to generate proto files is a + yet I would love to skip code->proto->protoc->code process for now.

Comment: What version of python / protobuf are you working with?

Comment: Any protobuf version, python 2.7 if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem. I wanted to be able to store objects in database and at the same time serialize them using protobuf.

Approach I used was to define objects in SQLAlchemy and then, using SQLAlchemy reflection (inspect method) wrote *.proto file generator utility.

Then have to invoke protoc normally to get protobuf classes for those defined in SQLAlchemy objects. So after each change in SQLAlchemy object definition I have to invoke script building proto files and invoking protoc. This works surprisingly well.

Other option I was considering was to design object definition format and generators that could generate SQLAlchemy objects and protobuf objects. I decided against it because this object definition format should be able to contain all information to build SQLAlchemy objects (indexes, constraints, triggers) which was like redesigning what SQLAlchemy already done nicely but you may don't need such rich object definition and this approach might be perfect for you.

I took idea of developing my own object definition from book Pragmatic Programmer, where you can read more about it.

Comment: Can you share your `.proto file generator utility`